# node dependency stopped working

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vue-loader

I'm making a Vue app and one of the dependencies is failing due to calling of an undefined function:

`vue-range-slider.cjs.js:150Uncaught ReferenceError: _h is not defined`

I thought this could be due to peer dependencies updating and breaking so I removed all the ^ characters from my package.json

The problem persists. What further troubleshooting steps can I take?

Comment: Have you removed `node_modules` and than did `npm install`?

Comment: yes.. no change

Comment: have you had any success in finding a solution?

Comment: my solution was removing it from my project and using something else

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that internally the render function was renamed from `_h` to `_c` and you are probably using a component with pre-built js files.

The solutions are

- downgrading vue to prior 2.1.5 since this is where the bug was introduced (also downgrade `vue-template-compiler` to same version)
- wait for vue-range-slider developers to fix it
- fix it yourself and pull request

Where fixing means distributing the source instead of the pre-built files.

Here is where the error happened:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/commit/4b51ad048306367a6fb6fbee7445e086d855f31e